# How can I use referenceSpaceType bounded-floor if available, else local-floor in AFRAME?

Tags: aframe, webxr

How can I use `referenceSpaceType` `bounded-floor` if available, else `local-floor` in AFRAME?

According to https://aframe.io/docs/1.4.0/components/webxr.html#referencespacetype, I can only give one value, but to be flexible in the supported devices, I would like to have both options, with the `bounded-floor` the prefered one and even required, if in VR, but nor AR mode.

Comment: I think you'd have to write a component which will try to determine which is available, and then set the `webxr` attribute